# index of an URL after item disappears

Tags: itemize, indexing

Inside `\begin{itemize}` , if I add a `\index{text}` after the `\item`, the "text" from the index appears in the index after `\printindex` but disappears from the PDF file in the original position inside `itemize`. Any idea how to solve this?

**Update**
Base on your comments I have tested it again and thanks @moewe: You were absolutely right. Thanks for the idea of the mini-test. Anything in inside the `\index{text}` will disappear. In my original document I thought I saw the text, but apparently it was not like that. Here is what I used to test it now:

```
    \documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
    Lorem \index{ipsum} dolor \index{sit} amet.
    
    \index{Text} outside of itemize
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item as you see... \index{Another text} (here is missing) I have been trying to explain
        
    \end{itemize}
    \printindex
\end{document}
```

and it shows:

> Lorem dolor amet. outside of itemize • as you see... (here is missing)
> I have been trying to explain
> ------next page --------- Index Another text, 1 sit, 1 ipsum, 1 Text, 1
> -------end document

Comment: AFAIK `\index{<text>}` normally never prints anything in the document and always only sends something to the index. Not just inside `itemize` but everywhere.

Comment: I though that at the beginning, but all my other text within the marking /index{text} that is present in the rest of the document, appears in the original place in addition to the Index at the end of the document. All except the ones inside itemize. Maybe an unknown bug?

Comment: Show a small but complete example. Then we don't have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: I just tested a small example with the standard `makeidx` package and could verify that `\index{<text>}` only sends `<text>` off to the index and does not print anything itself. See https://gist.github.com/moewew/e9e5f119c977b33c66504e87fe8d066b. If your document does something different, we really needs to see an example document that shows what you are doing.

Comment: so, is there any kind of indexing that just selects / marks the words for the index but it does not remove them from the text after marking them?

Comment: I am not aware of one, but you can easily define it yourself `\newcommand*{\myindex}[1]{#1\index{#1}}`. Then `\myindex{<text>}` prints `<text>` and indexes it. I'm guessing this isn't the default, because an `\index` that doesn't print the text is more flexible. You can for example do `dogs\index{dog}` or `continuous function\index{function!continuous}`, where printed text and indexed text do not agree.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks. I think I need to dig in the programming aspects of Latex. Until yesterday I did not know it was possible (LOL). I have already changed all my text simulating your 'dogs \index{dogs}' example.